# HTML code works on Chrome but not IE

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

Anyone know why this works on Chrome but not IE? I am using IE 10/11

I am trying to incorporate this code into a Windows Widget, so I need it to work on IE.

I heard win 7 gadgets will render using the latest version of IE installed but this code doesn't seem to run on IE at all. Please help.

```
var xmlhttp;

function init() {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    }
}

function SendRequest() {

    var data = "<some data>";

    var url = "some url";


    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {


            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            txt = "";

            x = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('id,owner,status');
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                txt = txt + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "&nbsp";
            }

            document.write(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get if you open IE's console and run the script in debug mode? Where is the script failing? Adding some more detail, and perhaps formatting your code, may help people solve the issue.

Comment: `document.write(txt)` Do not use document.write! Bad bad bad practice

Comment: Do not set the content-type. If you'd open the console in Chrome, you'll see the message that Chrome refused to set the unsafe header content-type.

Comment: I assume this is running locally? IE won't run this due to cross site domain restrictions. It needs to run on a proper webserver over http(s)

Comment: Hi.. I got this to work on IE but it wont display on the Gadget. Any ideas?